# Graph Theory: True or False

Tags: graph-theory

A couple of True/False problems I am working through. No full proof is required just whether the statements are valid or not.

> 1) If $G$ contains a closed walk, then $G$ contains a cycle.

False

> 2) Let $G$ be a connected graph. If $G$ has no bridges, then $G$ has no cut vertices.

False. A counterexample is pretty easy to generate; two triangles with a common vertex will     yield a graph with 5 vertices and 6 edges that contains 1 cut vertex and no bridges.

> 3) Suppose $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic graphs. If $G$ is a tree, then $H$ is a tree.

True

> 4) Suppose $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic graphs. If $G$ is connected, then $H$ is connected.

True

> 5) If every connected component of $G$ is bipartite, then $G$ is bipartite.

True

> 6) If $G$ is a regular tree, the $G$ is $K_1$ or $K_2$.

True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is false. A cycle is a closed walk **with no repeated vertices** except for ending up at the vertex where it started. The $2$-point path $P_2$ has a closed walk (walk from one end to the other and back again) but no cycles.

(5) is true. (It may help to recall that a graph is bipartite if and only if it's $2$-colorable. More generally, a graph is $n$-colorable if and only if every connected component is $n$-colorable.)

The rest of your answers are correct. The fact you're not **sure** about the answers to (3) and (4) is a little troubling. Maybe you aren't quite clear on the concept of isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

(1) is false by counterexample from bof.  (2) is like you say.

**Concerning isomorphic graphs** (3) and (4)

You should know that the term *isomorphic* literally means they are the same graph.  All you have to do is move the vertices around and you get the same graph.  So of course if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, then they are either both trees or both not, and they are either both connected or both not, because they are the same graph.

**Concerning bipartite graphs** (5)

Let $C_1, C_2, C_3, \ldots$ be the connected components of a graph $G$, and suppose they are bipartite with vertex sets $C_1 = A_1 \cup B_1, C_2 = A_2 \cup B_2, C_3 = A_3 \cup B_3, \ldots$, i.e. $A_i$ are the first part and $B_i$ are the second part of each connected component.  Then you should be able to show that $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots$ and $B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \cdots$ form two disjoint sets of vertices whose union is $G$, and that this makes $G$ bipartite (no two vertices in $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots$ are connected by an edge, and same for $B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \cdots$).

**Concerning regular trees** (6)

This is true, because [every tree has leaves](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Tree_has_Leaf_Nodes).  So you are correct.

Comment: I don't get 6. Can you help? If a tree is regular it means , that every inside vertex has the same - degree , right? K1 and K2 are the graphs where every vertex has degree 1 and 2 accordingly. What am I missing?

Comment: @brucebanner If a tree has any more than 2 vertices, it can't be regular because it will have some leaves (degree 1) and some non-leaves (degree 2 or more).